# wrong output magento-check.php

Tags: magento-1.9

**This is what magento-check.php on the site on my new hosting looks like:**

[image: This is what magento-check.php on the site on my new hosting looks like:]

**While it looks like this on my old hosting**

[image: While it looks like this on my old hosting]

What does this mean?

Comment: your magento-check.php contain some error.. might some tag missing!!!!!!!! check thoroughly

Comment: Stupid of me. Thought I had used the same file. Apologies, my mistake. But thank you.

Comment: check php short_tag enable or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit the `magento-check.php` flag and replace on the first line `<?` with `<?php`.
you get the error because your new server does not have short tags enabled and your old one did.
Also look for short tag openings in the rest of the code. I might have missed some.
honestly I don't know how `magento-check.php` got out with short tags in it.